# Can you tell me more about this robot?

Tags: robotics

A robot I can't find information on.

**CORRECTION**
  -  The article and or advertisement was in 1986 ( not 1985 ) .

I noticed an article and or advertisement in 1986, in the main city-wide newspaper ('mercury') in the city where this robot-factory was located.
( I don't have access to archives, etc.)

If there was also an advertisement, it was not in the small-ads, it was on a page the same as or near the article .

- Here's their webpage with some of their robots, in the page-source-code for that page you can see more text about the robot-pictures: http://www.southcom.com.au/~robot/robot.html
- The robot in the article and/or advertisement in 1986,  was a  home-hobby-robot  or  home-robot  that had one or two cameras built-in.
- It claimed (from memory, not sure if I'm 100% correct) to have object-recognition using the camera/cameras-?, and various other things.
- I don't know if it also included the area-mapping that some of their other robots did.
- It may or may not, have looked like their Chester or T-Bot robot or some type of similar looking robot.
- Both the advertisement and or article, were published in the same paper/publishing-date.
- This company also made various other hobby or home robots, that I know nothing about.
  They were on a similar level to the Androbot company robots like [Topo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topo_(robot)), which were RC or infrared controlled from home-computers, however, the robots from the company in the newspaper article seemed to be more advanced since they were autonomous.

A copy of that article and or advertisement is the reason for posting this question, it would confirm what I remember .

Comment: Chester looks a bit like the Tomy Omnibot from 1984, but no cameras: http://www.theoldrobots.com/omnibot.html

Comment: Do we need an `identify-this-robot` tag?

Comment: The only reason for my interest is because I definitely remember the article and or advertisement said it had a camera ( maybe two, stereo-vision, can't remember ) and featured  object-recognition. It said it was made in that city . Maybe back then they could of claimed visual-object-detection for navigation as being 'object-recognition', since even today a mobile robot has problems achieving that . Stereo-vision could of been another way of determining distance of an object . I think this company also developed robots for Tomy and maybe others .